# Does a 3/4x16tpi for a 5/8 plain spindle adapter exist?

Tags: lathe, lathe-chuck

It may be bad form to ask for a product recommendation here, but it's tough to do web searches for these things. Apologies if this question is out-of-line.

I just picked-up a 3-jaw 3-3/8" lathe chuck at a yard sale and it looks like it's in great shape. The problem is that it's got a 3/4x16tpi threaded hole and my lathe (a vintage 1950 Shopsmith 10ER) has a 5/8" plain spindle.

I don't seem to be able to find much in the way of spindle adapters with 3/4x16tpi outer threads, let alone with a 5/8 plain internal bore. Does such a beast exist? Or will I have to get two adapters:

1. 5/8-plain to 1x8tpi
2. 1x8tpi to 3/4x16tpi

That seems like a lot of hardware for a rather short spindle.

Comment: Something like [this](https://www.pennstateind.com/store/L5818.html) but with 3/4x16tpi on the outside instead of 1x8tpi.

Comment: Have you considered getting another spindle with the same taper as your existing one and just swapping them?

Comment: You might also consider finding a local blacksmith (OK, fine, a machine shop) to inquire about having one made.

Comment: I've been told by a fairly reliable source that this item is actually a metal-working lathe chuck and not a woodworking one (though to my untrained eye, I can detect no reason why it would be), so I may actually sell this one and buy one that is more appropriate for my situation.

Answer (score 1):

Not a true answer to your question, however you say that your lathe spindle is plain (I take to mean unthreaded). Any spindle adaptor would therefore need a grub screw or similar to secure it. It would not be a difficult task for someone with a metal lathe to produce an adaptor.
My thought would be to use something like a drill arbour. You can certainly buy 2MT to ¾" 16tpi arbours, you would need to check the taper used on your lathe. To safely use with a chuck you would need one that takes a drawbar through the lathes headstock to secure in place.
In a comment you said you had been told this is a metal working chuck, but didn't see the difference. The main give away is that it is three jaw - ideal for holding perfectly round bar stock, less ideal for softer and less round wood stock. Chuck's designed for wood *tend* to be of the four jaw scroll (self centering) variety, and *tend* to use a dovetail or grip jaw rather than the step jaws often found on engineering/metal chucks. Of course an engineering chuck is perfectly usable for wood turning, it just *may not be* as good at holding wood as a chuck specifically designed for the purpose ;-)